# My output shows "[object HTMLInputElement]" rather than the sum of my inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple HTML page with four text boxes. In my output, I am only getting object HTMLInputElement.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <script>
        function nhap_number(){
            var a = document.nhap.number_a;
            var b = document.nhap.number_b;

        }
        function random_c(){
            var c = Math.round(Math.random()*100)%100;
            document.getElementById("number_c").value=c;
        }
        function random_d(){
            var d = Math.round(Math.random()*100)%100;
            document.getElementById("number_d").value=d;
        }
        function sum(number_a,number_b,number_c,number_d){
            return(number_a+number_b+number_c+number_d);
            alert("ddddddd");
        }
        function show(){
            myDiv = document.getElementById("show");
            myDiv.innerHTML = "sum: "+sum(number_a+number_b+number_c+number_d);
        }

    </script>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form name = "nhap">
                <p> input a: <input id = "number_a" type="text" placeholder="please input number a "/></p>
                <p> input b: <input id = "number_b" type="text" placeholder="please input number b "/></p>
                <p> input c: <input id = "number_c"  placeholder="random number c "/><input type="button" value="value_c" onClick="random_c();"/></p>
                <p> input d: <input id = "number_d"  placeholder="random number d "/><input type="button" value="value_d" onClick="random_d();"/></p>
                <input type="button" value="Valid Form" onClick="show();">
            </form>

        </div>
        <div id="show">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't include meaningless text in your questions (like the long strings of "ddddddddddddd" and "sssssssssssssssssss" that I've deleted). Also it helps if you give a brief explanation of what the code is supposed to do - you talked about wanting "our text boxes", but you *have* that...

Comment: Your code is hard to reason about, because of the structure. You have element selectors in functions. You might want to consider to get these out and store them in variables. After that you can get there values inside of your functions. So please restructure, believe if you want to be able to debug, code structure is key! :)

Answer (score 0):

You never defined `number_a`, `number_b`, ... and so on. Some browsers will define them as a HTML element being based on the `id`. So the value `number_a` will be referencing the HTML element with the `id` `number_a` in this case. Trying to print them will show the value `[object HTMLInputElement]`, you will want to get the `.value` property of them, then convert them to a number:

```
+number_a.value // note the "+" converts the string to a number
// or
+document.getElementById("number_a").value // recommenced
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in show() function

```
myDiv.innerHTML = "sum:"+sum(parseInt(document.getElementById('number_a').value)+parseInt(document.getElementById('number_b').value)+parseInt(document.getElementById('number_c').value)+parseInt(document.getElementById('number_d').value));
```

You were trying to add HTML elements together. Also do a parseInt of their values.

Comment: `parseInt()`? What if the user enters `4.5`?

Comment: Then use a parseFloat

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head>
 <script>
  function nhap_number(){
   var a = document.nhap.number_a;
   var b = document.nhap.number_b;
   
  }
  function random_c(){
   var c = Math.round(Math.random()*100)%100;
   document.getElementById("number_c").value=c;
  }
  function random_d(){
   var d = Math.round(Math.random()*100)%100;
   document.getElementById("number_d").value=d;
  }
  function sum(number_a,number_b,number_c,number_d){
   return(Number(number_a.value)+Number(number_b.value)+Number(number_c.value)+Number(number_d.value));
  }
  function show(){
   myDiv = document.getElementById("show");
          debugger;
   myDiv.innerHTML = "sum: "+sum(number_a,number_b,number_c,number_d);
  }
  
 </script>
 <body>
  <div>
   <form name = "nhap">
    <p> nhap a: <input id = "number_a" type="text" placeholder="please input number a "/></p>
    <p> nhap b: <input id = "number_b" type="text" placeholder="please input number b "/></p>
    <p> nhap c: <input id = "number_c"  placeholder="random number c "/><input type="button" value="value_c" onClick="random_c();"/></p>
    <p> nhap d: <input id = "number_d"  placeholder="random number d "/><input type="button" value="value_d" onClick="random_d();"/></p>
    <input type="button" value="Valid Form" onClick="show();">
   </form>
   
  </div>
  <div id="show">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```